# Rest API in laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream

I have integrated Jetstream for user authentication (login, signup, forget password) in my Laravel web application. I am currently in the process of creating REST API endpoints using the Laravel Sanctum library. However, I'm facing confusion regarding how to expose the endpoints for login, logout, and user registration in the REST API, which will allow me to use these functionalities in my mobile application.